# sharepoint licensing migration to 2008 causing complete failure

Tags: c#, sharepoint, licensing

I currently use license.validate to check if my product is valid in sharepoint on windows 2003, i keep the license in the 12 hive and it all works.
i am testing the same code on 2008 and the whole web application just hangs!

Could this be a permissions problem?

Any help would be much appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, I found the problem in the logs and it refers to an embedded C++ MFC Dll, that I can't debug into, but that is a different problem for a new thread... Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Provide us please with more information that could help troubleshoot your problem.

1. Check Event Viewer
2. Check SharePoint ULS logs at `%CommonProgramFiles%\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\12\LOGS`